# How to import sibling file within a package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
NameChanger

  -main.py
  -__init__.py

  ui
    -__init__.py
    -utils.py

  utils
    -__init__.py
    -file.py
```

I want to import `NameChanger/utils/file.py` in `NameChanger/ui/utils.py`.

So I tried `from NameChanger.utils import file` but this error occurred `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NameChanger'`.

and I also tried `from ...NameChanger.utils import file` and this error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` occurred.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `from utils import file`?

Comment: How are you executing your Python code? More importantly, *from where*? Because 90% of the times, this causes the import errors. Do *not* execute Python code *inside* a package. Run an external script, outside, the package directory, that imports the package instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ui/utils.py`, use a relative import.

```
from . import utils.file
```

`NameChanger` itself is likely not in your search path (nor does it need to be). But since `NameChanger` is a package, the relative import in a module contained in a *subpackage* of `NameChanger` should work.

---

I originally suggested

```
from .utils import file
```

which would only work if `utils` really had `file` as a module-level attribute, which is generally not the case for a package.

Comment: thank you for the comment. but it didnt work too
`ImportError: cannot import name 'file' from 'ui.utils'`

Comment: ah wait the file name

Comment: I also mess this up. Packages don't automatically have their modules exposed as attributes. Try `from . import utils.file` as well.